# Dynamic like query in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Can a dynamic query be written in spring data rest as follows. If not then how to achieve a similar functionality:

```
    @Query("select s from Screen s where s.#searchColumn like:searchValue%")
    @RestResource(path="byString")
    Page findAll(
            @Param("searchColumn") String searchColumn,
            @Param("searchValue") String searchValue,
            Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved

Repo

```
@Query("select o from Screen o where "
            + "(o.screenName like :val% and :prop = 'screenName') or "
            + "(o.address like :val% and :prop = 'address')")
@RestResource(path="byString")
Page findAll(
        @Param("prop") String prop,
        @Param("val") String val,
        Pageable pageable);
```

Query:

```
/api/screens/search/byString?prop=address&val=a
```

Tested it with prop=address as well as prop=screenName. Working :)

Answer (score 0):

No. Spring Data JPA support [only](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions) `entityName` variables inside SpEL based query templates

For dynamic queries use:

- [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)
- [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)
- [Querydsl Extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)

Comment: its possible. check my answer.

Comment: @ArslanAnjum your approach is not entirely correct cause it uses a fixed columns. But your question meant dynamic columns (i.e. dynamic conditions)...