# Select data with a like condtion

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Good day,

- I'm trying to select for example all insurence numbers starting with 1, but I'm just receiving the rows with 1 and not all starting with 1.
- And I want to receive just the ones expiring in 30 days.

How do I have to change my code that the 2 conditions work? 
I already tried a few examples how I could change my query but none of them worked.

Additionally I added my code:

Repository:

```
@Query("From PERSON where exdate > current_date - to_char(30) and insnr like :insnr%") 
       Stream<PERSON> findAllWithSearchParams(@Param("insnr") String insnr);
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired 
   private PersonService personService; 
   @RequestMapping(value="/person/list/**") 
   public List<Person> loadPersonList(   
                   @RequestParam(value = "insnr" ,required=false) String insnr) throws ParseException {         
       mysearch.setInsnr(insnr); 
       return personService.all(mysearch).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
   }
```

Service:

```
@Service 
public class PersonService { 

    @Autowired 
    private PersonRepository personRepository;         
    public Stream<Person> all(Person mysearch){ 
        return personRepository 
               .findAll(Example.of(mysearch)) 
               .stream() 
               .map(Person::fromPerson); 
   } 
}
```

Class Person:

```
public class Person { 

    public Integer index; 
    public String firstname; 
    public String lastname; 
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy") 
    public Date exdate; 
    public String insnr; 

    private Person(Integer index, String firstname, String lastname, Date exdate, String insnr){ 
        this.index=index; 
        this.firstname=firstname; 
        this.lastname=lastname; 
        this.exdate=exdate; 
        this.insnr=insnr; 
    } 

    public static Person fromPerson(Person person){ 
        return person == null ? null : new Person(person.getIndex(), person.getFirstname(), person.getLastname(), person.getExdate(), person.getInsnr()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: JPQL does not start with "FROM". There is no such `to_char` function. Any basic JPA doc would show this

Comment: If you have a problem, you could just DEBUG it. Look at the SQL generated by your JPA provider (you don't mention which it is) is the start point, which you don't seem to have done ...

Answer (score 1):

You can change your repository with

```
List<Person> findByExdateAfterAndInsnrStartingWith(Date exdate, String insnr);
```

And you can call that method with the date you want and with "1" as `insnr`

Answer (score 1):

I used the like condition in this way:

```
@Query("select ....... where codition and date like  CONCAT('%','-',:m,'-',:d)")
```

So in your case should be:

```
@Query("From PERSON where exdate > current_date - to_char(30) and insnr like CONCAT(:insnr,'%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much easier if you use Keyword **Like** and **After** in your repository method for example

```
List<Person> findByExdateAfterAndInsnrLike(Date date,String 
like);
```

this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692717/2494123 and [Supported keywords inside method names
Keyword Sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)